# Can instance attribute be immutable in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, immutability

I'd like to set an instance attribute in `__init__` and then disallow any change to it. Is there such a mechanism in Python OOP. More specifically, I am using Python 3.7.

Before you down vote it as a duplicate, note that I am talking about the immutability of a `instance attribute` instead of that of the `class instance` themselves like the suggested similar question titles were asking about.

Comment: There is no good way to make this absolutely safe, but generally in Python, you'd use a property and not define a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

#### 1. Final type

Use mypy and the `Final` type from `typing_extensions`. This is only checked statically with mypy, not enforced at runtime.

```
$ pip install typing_extensions
```

---

```
from typing_extensions import Final

class Spam:
    foo: Final[int]
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
```

This should work as of this writing, but the `typing_extensions` are still kind of experimental, and may change. Guido himself has been working on mypy, so it might even end up in the standard library `typing` module.

#### 2. @property

Use a property (which can be circumvented, but probably not on accident) either--

Without a setter. You still have to store the variable somewhere. Maybe with a `_`-prefixed name, or in a closure, or directly on the instance dict with `vars` (which will bypass the descriptor function from `@property`).

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        vars(self)['foo'] = foo
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return vars(self)['foo']
```

Or with a setter that checks if it's already set, and raises an exception if it is. This lets you set it the first time with the normal syntax, but it's probably not worth the bother if you're setting it in `__init__`.

#### 3. subclass tuple

Inherit from `tuple`. You'll have to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`. You get real immutability, but these are no longer attributes per se and you have to access them with integer subscripts (`self[0]` etc.).  Inheriting from `tuple` means you get all the tuple methods too, which you may not want.

If you still want the dot access, you can try creating a `collections.namedtuple` instead, and inherit from that.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Spam(namedtuple('Spam', 'foo')):
    def __new__(cls, foo):
        return super().__new__(cls, foo)
    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.foo)
```

Of course, you inherit even more methods this way.

See also, `typing.NamedTuple`.

Comment: 3. you mean like class `MyClass(tuple)`? This way, can I still access these values with a name label such as `print(my_object.name)`?

Comment: For #2, you can store the data as `my_instance.__dict__['property_name']` then you really can't mess with it unintentionally.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, but this way, I can still do `my_instance.property_name = xxx` out of carelessness, or am I missing the point here?

Comment: @gilch, still on #3, if I have a large number of attributes on `Spam`, then I'd have to inherit from a `namedtuple` that has a long list of names, right? such as: `class Spam(namedtupe('attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4', 'attr5', ...))`

Comment: @Indominus yes, the field names are required by the namedtuple callable. You can use any iterable of the names, or even a single whitespace-separated string listing them. Alternatively, you could try [typing.NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)

Comment: @Indominus `my_instance.property_name = xxx` will cause an AttributeError, because the property shadows the value in the dict. The only way to write to the attribute is to access the instance dict directly, which you really can't do by accident.

Comment: @MadPhysicist nice trick. I incorporated that, but I used `vars` instead of `__dict__`, which I think reads better.

Comment: @Indominus. Just keep in mind that the first argument to a namedtuple is a class name and the second is a list of field names. You can create the field names outside the actual class declaration.

Comment: @gilch. Reads better, but may not be as reliable. It should be fine here though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the only way I can imagine it being unreliable is if you shadow the `vars` builtin for some reason. That goes for any builtin though. I also think `next(foo)` or `str(foo)` are usually preferable to `foo.__next__()` or `foo.__str__()`. We have these builtins for a reason.